# CSS to add transparency to white background when hovering on dropdown menu in blogger

Tags: drop-down-menu, transparency, blogger

I was hoping someone could help me with CSS to make the child options that appear when hovering on my custom dropdown menu more transparent in Blogger.

[image: xxx screenshot xxx]

My site is: www.thenorthernmagnolia.com

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you using any layout managers like bootstrap?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, making something transparent is very easy in CSS if you're already familiar with changing the background color. Use the RGBA function, like this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
```

Parameters go, in order: Red Value, Green Value, Blue value, Alpha value. Google has a color picker you can play with for these values.

Alpha value is the opacity, a value of 1 will be non-opaque, and 0 will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following CSS to make the dropdown menu more transparent -

```
#cssnav > li > ul > li a, #cssnav > li > ul > li, #cssnav > li > ul, #cssnav > li > ul > li a:hover {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
}
```

[image: transparent background]